# How much potential is enough?

Tags: megami-quest-2

The Rusty Dagger seems to require Lv5, the Bronze Sword Lv10, the Iron Hammer Lv15... But after this point the level requirements for the various equipment upgrades seem to stop following a predictable path. The Titanium Blade seems to be somewhere between Lv35 and Lv40, the Halberd is around Lv75. A few other things I've managed to equip, but only after using an item that increases a character's EXP by 100,000. That gives a window of several dozen levels, which makes pinning down the requirements for some of the stronger equipment a pain.

Is there any way to tell exactly how much 'potential' a character has to have before a given piece of equipment can be equipped? Failing that, What *are* the level requirements of each piece of equipment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure but from experimentation it seems that your potential has to be at least as high as the stat increase the item provides.

Therefore if an item increases strength by 200 your potential needs to be at least 200, If a item increases multiple stats then it is the total increase which counts

Comment: Hmm... Seems reasonable. Although some testing seems to indicate that only the primary stat of the equipment counts. Both the Scythe of Death (str+4400 mag+360), and Damascus Claw (str+4000 spd+1200) can be equipped on a character with 4600 potential.

Comment: What about items that boost a stat by a multiplier, e.g. Gram?